# Обратное действие к makemigrations\migrate Django

Tags: python, django

Всем привет! Вопрос такой. Ситуация : есть приложение работающее на Django. Есть база данных уже заполненная данными. Мне нужно в своем приложении иметь доступ к ЭТОЙ базе данных. Есть ли способ в Django создать модели по уже имеющейся,заполненной данными базе ?

Comment: Попробуйте [`inspectdb`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb).

Comment: Это [описано в документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/legacy-databases/).

Comment: То,что надо,спасибо!